# How to display second section first in iOS UITableView programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with many sections. Normally iOS displays first section first in UITableView. In my case, I want to display second section first. I think it is just like in HTML bookmark with archor tag. Is it possible to do it programatically? And let me know how to do it.

Comment: `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

Comment: Swap the sections from data source..

Comment: Thanks @Larme. You save my time. I didn't know I can scroll to desire position in UITableView programatically. I can solve the problem with your tip.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know I can scroll to desire position in UITableView programatically. I scroll to second section with the code snippet below.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Display second section first
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

References

[UItableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath not displaying last row correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028239/uitableview-scrolltorowatindexpath-not-displaying-last-row-correctly)

[iOS UItableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514770/ios-uitableview-scrolltorowatindexpath-not-working-anymore)